# How to correct the format of an XML file (add a header + add a queue + delete the incomplete part) using a python script

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

i want to process an very big XML file (> 3 Gigabyte) with python3, but the problem is that the xml file is incomplete like this :

```
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank>4</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
<country name="Panama">
    <rank>68</rank>
```

the result that i'm looking for is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank>4</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
</data>
```

So, i have to add the header part (showed below) to the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
```

then, delete the incomplete part (showed below) of the xml file :

```
<country name="Panama">
    <rank>68</rank>
```

and finally, add the queue part (showed below) to the XML file :

```
</data>
```

ALL these process must be done by a Python script.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read successive lines into a buffer, print and empty the buffer when you have completed another `<country>...</country>` entry.

```
import fileinput

print('<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<data>\n')
country=[]
for line in fileinput.input():
    country.append(line)
    if '</country>' in line:
        print(''.join(country), end='')
        country=[]
print('</data>\n')
```

To avoid printing a spurious newline between entries, I use `end=''`.  If you want a Python 2 solution, [the fix is different for Python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space).

Personally, I would write this in Awk, which is quite effective when it comes to this kind of task.

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<data>" }
    { b = b (b ? ORS : "" ) $0 }
    /<\/country>/ { print b; b=""; }
    END { print "</data>" }' country.xml
```

The ternary expression `(b ? ORS : "")` is to add a newline (Output Record Separator) only when `b` isn't empty, i.e. avoid adding a newline before the first member.